# Run tomcat from within a batch file inside IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: batch-file, intellij-idea

I have a tomcat that starts with a batch file (several conditions and parameters are treated inside the batch file). Let's call it *startTomcat.bat*. This batch file ends with

```
call %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

I know how to start *startTomcat.bat* from within IDEA (via external tools), but it will open another standalone cmd window where the tomcat actually starts / runs. I would like to have this latter console window inside IDEA. Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catalina.bat start` uses the `start` command which [spawns the new console window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491005(v=technet.10)):

```
:doStart
shift
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=Tomcat
set _EXECJAVA=start "%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd
```

Notice this line: `set _EXECJAVA=`**start**`"%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%.`

Use `catalina.bat run` instead to not open a new console window.